# Adding 3rd party PHP classes to Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, tcpdf

I am new to Zend Framework. I am trying to integrate TCPDF with my controller so that I can generate PDFs on the fly. I'd like to put the entire TCPDF folder in library/tcpf (instead of the public folder where it is now) and have the application run but I dont seem to be able to get Zend to see it and use it. I read through the loader documentation but I'm still confused. Help please.

Regards,
Joe Chin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if Zend_Loader will help you too much here as TCPDF appears to only have one class and does not follow the PEAR style class naming conventions. So if I were you I'd extract it all into library/tcpf as you suggested and then just require in library/tcpdf/tcpdf.php when you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the info Tim. I have it in my library folder now and all is working well. Cheers.